# How to use zombie objects with Xamarin.mac and Visual Studio

Tags: macos, xamarin, monodevelop

I know how to enable zombie objects in XCode ([How to enable NSZombie in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode)). But could i do the same for Xamarin.Mac application and how?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to trace an issue in the Xamarin.Mac Mono runtime? Otherwise, you might want to look at the Xamarin Profiler to monitor/trace IL object allocations/orphans

Comment: I'm debugging in Visual Studio

Comment: Yes, i can do it with profiler. Thank you